# Checking and adding data to url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a `HeaderData` model, it has two fields:

```
$table->string('url');
$table->text('data');
```

Through `BaseController`, I added one method for all controllers, so as not to repeat the code:

```
protected $header_data;

public function __construct() 
{
    $this->header_data = HeaderData::all();
    
    View::share('header_data', $this->header_data);
}
```

And I display this on the pages, the `data` field in the `head`:

```
@foreach ($header_data as $data)
    {!! $data->data !!}
@endforeach
```

But for me it displays all the `data` that is there, but I only need it for the current page, so there is a `url` field. I need to do a type check, if we are on the page that is specified in the `url` field, then we display the `data` field for the same page. Here's an example:

Add

```
"url": "/contacts"
"data": "<title>Contacts TEST</title>
<meta name="description"  content="test CONTACTS" />"
```

Let's say we check that if we are now on the contacts page, then we display the `data` field only for contacts. If the page is a let's say blog, then we display the `data` for the blog.

But I can't figure out how to do this yet, can anyone tell me? Can I do it right in this controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller

```
$header_data = HeaderData::where(['url'=>Route::currentRouteName()])->first();
```

in blade

```
{!! $header_data->data !!}
```

or you can try

```
@foreach($header_data as $data)
    @if(Route::currentRouteName() === $data->url)
        {!! $header_data->data !!}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok, this is great, I still have a question, this is all for non-dynamic pages. But I suppose I have a name in the `blog/{slug}` route, and I create the `blog/article_1` `url`. How can I make a check here?

Comment: public function show($slug) 
{
   $header_data = HeaderData::where(['url'=>$slug])->first();    
  // other codes